Scan other files where a collection is linked
Good Morning,
I have a file "ej. windows.blend" where there are several collections "Window A, Window B, etc."
And I have another files that are buildings "Building 1.blend, Building 2.blend, etc."
Every building has a windows collection Linked.
From the file "Windows.blend", is it possible to know in which buildings is linked a collection ej. "Window A", instead of opening each building and check which window collection is linked?
Thanks a lot,
